# ElasticSearch IndexMissingException while using prepareGet

Tags: java, elasticsearch, get

I am trying to get data from elasticsearch using Java's GET API. but I keep on getting the IndexMisingException.

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.indices.IndexMissingException: [logstash-*] missing
>   at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaData.concreteIndices(MetaData.java:768)
>   at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaData.concreteIndices(MetaData.java:691)
>   at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaData.concreteSingleIndex(MetaData.java:748)
>   at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.shard.TransportShardSingleOperationAction$AsyncSingleAction.<init>(TransportShardSingleOperationAction.java:139)
>   at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.shard.TransportShardSingleOperationAction$AsyncSingleAction.<init>(TransportShardSingleOperationAction.java:116)
>   at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.shard.TransportShardSingleOperationAction.doExecute(TransportShardSingleOperationAction.java:89)
>   at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.shard.TransportShardSingleOperationAction.doExecute(TransportShardSingleOperationAction.java:55)
>   at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:75)
>   at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.execute(NodeClient.java:98)
>   at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.get(AbstractClient.java:193)
>   at org.elasticsearch.action.get.GetRequestBuilder.doExecute(GetRequestBuilder.java:201)
>   at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:91)
>   at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:65)
>   at elasticConnection.ClientElastic.main(ClientElastic.java:18)
> ```

I have the Index in elasticsearch.

> ```
> health status **index**               pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
>
> yellow open   **events**                5   1         39            0     48.7kb         48.7kb 
>
> yellow open   **logstash-2016.03.30**   5   1        152            0    137.8kb        137.8kb
> ```

please help.

Comment: have you checked the mappings of the index?

Comment: @Satya this is what I am using

  "_index": "events",
            "_type": "logs",
            "_id": "AVPKTE_DpbJsjiEptPkh",
            "_score": 1,

and this is what I am using

  GetResponse getResponse = client.prepareGet("events", "logs", "*").execute().actionGet();

I am new to elasticsearch so am I correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your indexes are still waiting for replica, which generally we avoid when working on a single node.

Run this command on your local host :

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_settings' -d '{ "index" : { "number_of_replicas" : 0 } }'
```

This should change the index status to **green** and your program should be good to go.

Comment: The index status did change to **Green** but the error is still there.

Comment: can you try restarting elasticsearch and see if it works

Comment: Same thing. same exception. Is there anything else we can do?